# Python dicom resizing: error file not found

Tags: python, resize, png

so for some reason it doesn't find my file when I'm passing it trough "preprocess"
But the file is there and when I run it, i see in fileList all the dicom files.
any suggestions what I'm doing wrong?

thx

I get the following error

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '12-1.dcm'

```
import dicom
    from scipy.ndimage.interpolation import zoom
    import os 
   import imageio


        def add_gaussian_noise(inp, expected_noise_ratio=0.05):
            image = inp.copy()
            if len(image.shape) == 2:
                row,col= image.shape
                ch = 1
            else:
                row,col,ch= image.shape
            mean = 0.
            var = 0.1
            sigma = var**0.5
            gauss = np.random.normal(mean,sigma,(row,col)) * expected_noise_ratio
            gauss = gauss.reshape(row,col)
            noisy = image + gauss
            return noisy

        def normalize(img):
            arr = img.copy().astype(np.float)
            M = np.float(np.max(img))
            if M != 0:
                arr *= 1./M
            return arr

        def preprocess(filename, resize_ratio=0.25):
            img = dicom.read_file(filename).pixel_array
            img = normalize(zoom(img, resize_ratio))
            img = add_gaussian_noise(img)
            return img

    ### filelist contains all *.dcm files

    PathDicom = "dicom_pics/"

    for dirName, subdirList, fileList in os.walk(PathDicom):
        for dicom_file in fileList:
            pp_image = preprocess(dicom_file)
            imageio.imwrite(dicom_file.replace("dcm","png"), pp_image, "png")
```

Comment: The `dicom_file` name is incorrect. Try:
`pp_image = preprocess(os.path.join(dirName, dicom_file))`

Comment: thx. that did the trick ;)